# Cluster of Wowza Streaming Engines?

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, video-processing, live-streaming, wowza

I am exploring Wowza as a potential solution for a video streaming product we are developing.

We need to be able to streams ~400 live channels. Per my understanding no single Wowza engine instance / machine can handle that kind of load.

Going through community forum at Wowza, the typically recommended solution([here](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/3124/setting-up-multiple-live-streams.html)) is to get a bigger box (higher CPU/RAM) but that just wont work in our case given the scale needed.

Advice given in the docs ([here](https://www.wowza.com/docs/scaling-and-load-balancing#large-server-cluster)) seems to refer to only client / output scaling (let me know if am wrong). While for output scaling, we anyways are going to use a CDN. We are really looking for a solution that can scale over 100s of input streams to work on top off.

Questions -

1. Does wowza engine support horizontal scaling where we can deploy a cluster of wowza instances that can handle as many streams as we need?
2. If Ye, what sort of tooling would we need to do on top it to manage the cluster?
3. Are there any alternative cost effective solutions that you can suggest for such a scale of deployment? Wowza is pretty expensive

The last question is slightly broad but any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that [Wowza Cloud API](https://www.wowza.com/pricing/streaming-cloud-plans/service-provider) is for this scenario. With that you can scale your transcoders up and down via the API based on how many you need. Scaling the servers yourself for a variable number of streams can get pretty complicated, but that looks like the best option for ingest scaling.

For an alternative, [Mux](https://mux.com/live) (my company) just launched a live streaming API that scales to as many live channels and viewers as you need without having to manage transcoding servers. If interested I'm happy to answer any questions, including around cost. [Here's the live API docs](https://docs.mux.com/docs/live-streaming).